# Kindle Reader no longer syncing correctly

Tags: sync

My Kindle 3rd gen has recently started not syncing to the right spot; it asks me if I want to go to the furthest pg read and I click "yes" and it goes but not far enough. It used to work fine; my software is up to date so any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Hold the power button or slider for about 20–30 seconds. Release it then hold it for about 5 seconds or until you see something happen on screen. That does a power on reset. Obviously you’ll have to make sure it’s charged.

Alternatively you can start it as normal then:

1. From the Kindle Home screen, press Menu.
2. Select Settings.
3. Press Menu.
4. Select Reset to Factory Defaults.